# Extra large spherical joins

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are piecewise spherical complexes, then their spherical join $X * Y$ is CAT(1) if and only of $X$ and $Y$ are CAT(1) (see the appendix of the first Charney-Davis paper below). One of the definitions of CAT(1) in this context is: $X$ is CAT(1) if and only if all closed geodesics have length $\geq 2\pi$, and all closed geodesics in links of cells of $X$ have length $\geq 2\pi$. If one replaces the inequalities in the above definition by *strict* inequalities, one gets the definition of an *extra large* complex. This property is stable under small deformations of the metric (Moussong showed that the systole of a spherical complex is a lower-semicontinuous function of the metric structure; i.e. it is decreased by arbitrarily little when we make a small perturbation of the metric).

My question is: does the above theorem have an analogue for extra large complexes? That is, if $X$ and $Y$ are extra large, can we perturb the metric on $X * Y$ (for example, by lengthening all the new edges between $X$ and $Y$ to have length slightly greater than $\pi/2$) and obtain an extra large structure on $X * Y$?

One might hope that we can carefully lengthen all the new edges (between $X$ and $Y$) such that all the $\pi/2$ dihedral angles in all the links also increase slightly, but this seems rather a lot to ask. On the other hand, it seems plausible at least if $X$ and $Y$ are spheres; at least, any triangulation of the round sphere can be deformed to an extra large triangulation (see the second Charney-Davis paper below).

---

*Ruth Charney and Michael Davis*, [**Singular metrics of nonpositive curvature on branched covers of Riemannian manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2375063), *Amer. J. Math.* **115** (1993), no. 5, 929--1009.

*Ruth Charney and Michael Davis*, [**The polar dual of a convex polyhedral set in hyperbolic space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1029005308), *Michigan Math. J.* **42** (1995), no. 3, 479--510.